# Cannot convert Euro Currency to its Symbol

Tags: symfony

what i Need

- i need to convert the Euro currency symbol.
- I Have checked other country currencies its working except euro.

source code

```
     use Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle\CurrencyBundle;
    class EventDetailController extends Controller
    {

    $currenc = $data_fees[0]['currency'];
    $currenc=EURO 
    $currency= Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencySymbol($currenc);
     output : 
    }
```

- Problem im getting  Euro Currency is not converted to its symbol.

  Issue

  ```
  $currency= Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencySymbol('EUR'); 
  output : €
  ```
- i have checked all currency code are converted except euro.
- i have found solution buts it is static way.

  ```
              if ($currenc =='EURO')
              {
               $currency= Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencySymbol('EUR');
              }
              else
              {
               $currency= Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencySymbol($currenc); 
              }
  ```
- if its problem in symphony intln bundle suggest some solution to handle this issue.

Comment: Erm... in your source you work with "EURO", in your second example (which is basically the same) you work with the correct "EUR". You have to use the ISO 4217 names of the currencies

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong string `EURO`. As states in http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/currency_codes.htm currency code in ISO can be represented in two ways: a three-letter alphabetic code and a three-digit numeric code.

For Euro currency right currency code will be `EUR`. Check the whole list from ISO organisation: http://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html

Right code for your case will be:

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\ResourceBundle\CurrencyBundle;
class EventDetailController extends Controller
{
// ...
    $currenc = 'EUR'; 
    $currency = Intl::getCurrencyBundle()->getCurrencySymbol($currenc);
// ...
}
```